# How to Fix the "KILLED" Stuff During the make process

Tags: android, android-source

I am a newer for android development. Recently I just try to build the AOSP through its instruction.

Commands I used listed below:

```
$lunch full-eng
$make -j16
```

Then it began compiling. But something strange happened, which are listed below:

```
host C++: tblgen <= external/llvm/utils/TableGen/DAGISelMatcherOpt.cpp
host C++: tblgen <= external/llvm/utils/TableGen/DAGISelMatcher.cpp
host C++: tblgen <= external/llvm/utils/TableGen/DFAPacketizerEmitter.cpp
host C++: tblgen <= external/llvm/utils/TableGen/DisassemblerEmitter.cpp
host C++: tblgen <= external/llvm/utils/TableGen/EDEmitter.cpp
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aapt_intermediates/ResourceTable.o] Killed
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aapt_intermediates/Resource.o] Killed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/tblgen_intermediates/AsmMatcherEmitter.o] Killed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/tblgen_intermediates/AsmWriterEmitter.o] Killed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/tblgen_intermediates/CodeGenDAGPatterns.o] Killed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/tblgen_intermediates/CodeGenInstruction.o] Killed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/tblgen_intermediates/CodeGenRegisters.o] Killed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/tblgen_intermediates/CodeGenTarget.o] Killed
Killed
```

Then the compiling process stopped. Why is that? How to fix it?
Is there any recommended instruction about how to build a custom rom, or how to use the AOSP?

The instruction in the AOSP website is really unclear for me. (or I read a wrong instruction??)

Thank you!

Comment: There must be an error before that "Killed", please find it out and paste it out.

Comment: Is it possible that you have pressed ctrl+c during the build?

Comment: how many CPU's you have? Try: "make -jN", where N = processors_number + 1

Answer (score 3):

It is because compiler got out of memory. Try to increase RAM to 2GB or more and at least 10-12GB for swap partition